# C++ duration_cast<>(time_point_end - tine_point_start). count() overflows

Tags: c++, duration

**What I want to do, my project:**

I want to make a program that waits 0.5 seconds, for example, does something, let's say `cout << "Hello World"`, once and then again the same for about 10 times(this is a test for another program), but without sleep, sleep_for, sleep or anything similar BCS I don't want the processor to actually sleep, BCS at that time the processor does not just wait, it does nothing for that time, for these 0.5 seconds it does nothing and I don't want that, and the main reason is BCS it also doesn't take input.

**What I tried:**

What I tried was to keep two points in time(time_point start,end), duration_cast their difference (end - start) in a for loop ((int i = 0;i < 10;i++)), and if their difference was 500 milliseconds, then, cout << "Hello World\n";. 
My code looked something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main()
{
    time_point<steady_clock> t = steady_clock::now():
    for (int i = 0; i < 10;)
    {
        duration<double> d = steady_clock::now() - t;
        uint32_t a = duration_cast<milliseconds>(d).count();
        if (a >= 500)
        {
            cout << a << " Hello World!" << endl;
            t = steady_clock::now();
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**My problem:**

It overflows, most of the time, I don't know what exactly overflows, but a appears to be sometimes 6??? others 47??? (? =  some digit) 
    I tried many things, I ended up to something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main()
{
    time_point<high_resolution_clock> t = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i< 10;)
    {
        duration<double,ratio<1,1000000>> d = high_resolution_clock::now() - t;
        uint32_t a = duration_cast<microseconds>(d).count();
        if (d >= microseconds(500000) )
        {
            cout << a << " Hello World!" << endl;
            i++;
            t = high_resolution_clock::now();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It didn't really solve the problem, but the max value appears is `~1500(1500000 in microseconds) and when it happens it takes longer to print the message, I don't know if its still overflow, to be honest, but...

**Question**

Anyway, do you have any suggestions about how to stop the overflow or a completely different way to achieve what I want, even if you don't, thanks for spending time to read my question, I hope to express someone else's question if there someone who has the same question as me.

Comment: Please do *not* tag C++ questions with the C tag.

Comment: By overflow do you mean that the time span is higher than expected?

Comment: Your `for` loop only loops 10 times. If `a <= [timeout]` than you lose that iteration's print and you won't get 10 outputs. Its entirely normal that, as you increase the required delay, you will get fewer outputs.

Comment: Why do you think it overflows? Be more specific about the results you get, and explain the difference from the results you wanted instead, and explain _why_ you think you should get the results you wanted instead.

Comment: Your description of why you want this is confusing. Why do you want to prevent the processor from doing anything while waiting?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for or not.  But if not, maybe we can build on this to figure out what you want:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto t = steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        auto t1 = t + 500ms;
        while (steady_clock::now() < t1)
            ;
        cout << duration<double>(t1-t).count() << " Hello World!" << endl;
        t = t1;
    }
}
```

The code sets a `time_point` for 500ms in the future, and then enters a busy loop until that future `time_point` is now.